# Java 8 How Compose Functions without Lambdas?

Tags: java, function, lambda, function-composition

I've only seen examples such as the following for composing functions (or people using lambdas).

```
Function<A,B> inner = ....;
Function<B,C> outter = ....;
Function<A,C> result = outter.compose(inner);
```

I would like to compose the following functions using the "compose" feature and not just invoking them directly.

```
public class J{ 
  public static B inner(final A a){...}
  public static C outter(final B b){...}      
}
public class K{
  public static Function<A,C> result = (J::outter).compose(J::inner);
}
```

This doesn't compile.  I can't seem to be able to use that "compose" member of java.util.function.Function.  How do I do it for traditionally declared functions?  I would like to avoid the following:

```
public class K{
  public static Function<A,C> result = (a)-> J.outter(J.inner(a));
}
```

Can it be done??  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method references (and lambdas) need **context** for them to make sense in source code. That context describes the target functional interface, provides details for type inference for generics, etc.

The use of method references in

```
public static Function<A,C> result = (J::outter).compose(J::inner);
```

have no context. What should that first `J::outter` be? Why?

Apply a cast to give it that context

```
public static Function<A, C> result = ((Function<B, C>) J::outter).compose(J::inner);
```

which, in my opinion, is uglier than the lambda solution.

Comment: I've noticed a lot of questions along the lines "How do I do this thing with these concepts", and the real answer is "you can do it this way, but you shouldn't. Do it the 'classic' way."